# Quick way to know if a file is open on Linux?

Tags: python, linux

Is there a quick way (i.e. that minimizes time-to-answer) to find out if a file is open on Linux?

Let's say I have a process that writes a ton a files in a directory and another process which reads those files **once** they are finished writing, can the latter process know if a file is still being written to by the former process?

A Python based solution would be ideal, if possible.

**Note:** I understand I could be using a FIFO / Queue based solution but I am looking for something else.

Comment: Since you want to observe changes in the file system, inotify could be the answer. I have not tested it myself, but maybe this is related to your problem http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=663950

Comment: Nice question, lots of good different answers. With a little more information it may be easier to pick a front runner solution.

Comment: I've got 10,000's of files generated at each stage by process #1 and I'd like a quick way to pick-out the files that have been processed and hand those off to process #2.

Comment: yes I have full control of the environment.  I have used the "tmp file & rename" option in the past but I was looking for alternatives.

Comment: I would suggest that the "tmpfile & rename" is the most resilient method. If process #1 crashes or runs out of space, you do not have any half-complete "result files". You could combine this method with "inotify" to avoid the need to poll the directory

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can of course use INOTIFY feature of Linux, but it is safer to avoid the situation: let the writing process create the files (say data.tmp) which the reading process will definitely ignore. When the writer finishes, it should just rename the file for the reader (into say .dat). The rename operation guarantees that there may be no misunderstandings.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the PID of the writing process, in Linux you can simply query the /proc/{PID}/fd/ and see whether one of the links found there points to one of your files.

What you would do is, scan the directory, archiving the fact that fd 5 (say) points to /var/data/whatever/file1.log . Then store the file pointed to into an array.

At that point if a filename is in the array, the process has it in use.

So:

```
import os
# Here I use PID = 31824
path="/proc/%d/fd" % 31824
openfiles   = [ os.readlink("%s/%s" % (path, fname)) for fname in os.listdir(path) ]

if whatever in openfiles:
    # whatever is used by pid 31824.
```

Answer (score 2):

`lsof | grep filename` immediately comes to mind.

Answer (score 2):

You have a variety of options available:

- [Inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) is a feature that allows you to watch for file operations
- Writing process renames files when finished writing
- The program [fuser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuser_%28Unix%29) will let you query whether a file is in use
- Knowing the PID of the writer may let you query `/proc/PID/fd` for open file descriptors.

Answer (score 1):

I would use psutil ( https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil ) which also has the advantage of being cross-platform and provides many other useful system functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the 'first' process logic, the easy solution would be to write data to a temp file and rename the file once all the data is written.

Answer (score 1):

you can use **lsof** with **subprocess**

```
(output,error) = subprocess.Popen("lsof #absolute_file_path").communicate()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know (or can find) the process ID of the writing process you can use psutil library. `sudo pip install psutil` to get the library. Docs are here: http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/

```
>>> import psutil
>>> import os
>>> p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
>>> p.open_files()
[]
>>> f = open('foo.txt', 'w')
>>> p.open_files()
[openfile(path='/Users/mariaz/Downloads/foo.txt', fd=3)]
```

If you do not have access to the writing process, you'll need to run lsof as root and parse the output yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution using inotify. You will get a notification for every file in the directory being closed after a writing operation.

```
import os
import pyinotify

def Monitor(path):
    class PClose(pyinotify.ProcessEvent):
        def process_IN_CLOSE(self, event):
            f = event.name and os.path.join(event.path, event.name) or event.path
            print 'close event: ' + f

    wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()
    notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm, PClose())
    wm.add_watch(path, pyinotify.IN_CLOSE_WRITE)

    try:
        while 1:
            notifier.process_events()
            if notifier.check_events():
                notifier.read_events()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        notifier.stop()
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = "."
    Monitor(path)
```

However, since you are the one being in control of the process writing the files I'd vote for a different solution involving some kind of communication between the processes.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the modification time of the file and see if it has not been modified for a period of time. Since a file can be opened in update mode and be modified any time, you cannot be 100% sure that it will never be modified.

Comment: As you've mentioned, it's not a reliable method. Additionally, there are circumstances where data changes may be committed before the file metadata is updated, e.g. [fdatasync](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fdatasync).

Answer (score 0):

You can use fcntl module, afaik, it's has fcntl function that identical to C function, so something like `fcntl(fd, F_GETFL)` could be useful, but I'm not sure. Can you check is target file is blocked for writing by opening it in write mode?